# RectF goes out of borders on Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-view, ondraw

I'm improving a simple Android game called [Arkanoid](https://github.com/SlimShadys/Arkanoid), where I'm having a small problem drawing a RectF on a Canvas.

I implemented a power-up option where, if you take this power-up, the Paddle streches from a 200x Paddle to a 500x Paddle.

```
    private RectF r;
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Bitmap flipperBit;

    // Draw Paddle
    flipperBit = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.flipper);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);

    if (powerUpTaken) {
        r = new RectF(flipper.getX(), flipper.getY(), flipper.getX() + 500, flipper.getY() + 40);
    } else {
        r = new RectF(flipper.getX(), flipper.getY(), flipper.getX() + 200, flipper.getY() + 40);
    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(flipperBit, null, r, paint);
```

The main problem is that when I hit the powerup, the Paddle successfully streches from 200 to 500, but goes out of border as in the gif below, thinking it's still a 200x Paddle.
Please note that all of this , it's written inside the onDraw overrided-function.

I know, I need to implement a way to stretch the Paddle for x seconds, but as of now I want to make it work first.

Any suggestion would be really appreciated. :)

[image: 1.st]

Comment: Of course you have to check (pseudo-code) "(Bitmap.getWidth()+500) < Screen.getWidth()" and then denied the Canvas to draw more on its right....

Comment: So I checked it like this: If the width of the Bitmap + 500 is < of the screen width (1080), then draw me the Rectangle into the Canvas, but it still shows the same bug. Maybe I didn't quite get your reply but I appreciate your effort.

Comment: Comunque, vedo che sei Italiano, puoi anche contattarmi tramite mail o su Telegram ("SlimShadyss") :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  //set to ZERO if not needed
final cMargin = 10;
int cPaddingWidth;
final int cPaddingHeight = 40;
final RectF cRectF = new RectF();
if (powerUpTaken) cPaddingWidth = 500;
else cPaddingWidth = 200;
cRectF.left = Math.max(cMargin, flipper.getX());
cRectF.right = cRect.left + cPaddingWidth;
if (cRectF.right > (this.getWidth() - cMargin)) {
    cRectF.left = (this.getWidth() - cMargin) - cPaddingWidth;
    cRectF.right = cRectF.left + cPaddingWidth;
}
cRectF.top = Math.max(0, flipper.getY());
cRectF.bottom = cRect.top + cPaddingHeight;
r.set(cRectF);
```